# Can we add block reward contract in parity aura latter on

Tags: parity, block-reward

We know there is an option to add a block reward contract to incentivize authors of new block by using blockRewardContractAddress at chain engine specs.

> **Is it possible to add this property in the chain specs?**

Considering that the chain is running for a long time without any block reward contract or any kind of block reward.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just deploy the block reward contract as if you would do with any other smart contract and once the deployment succeeded, you can take the address and add it to the chain spec scheduling a hardfork to activate that contract:

```
"engine": {
  "authorityRound": {
    "params": {
      ...
      "blockRewardContractAddress": "0xCd3eB5B6A5a4DE398717a7309d31A6DA358976b1",
      "blockRewardContractTransition": 9876543
    }
  }
}
```

This would activate the contract at `0xCd3eB5B6A5a4DE398717a7309d31A6DA358976b1` on block `9_876_543`.